# Logging objc_msgSend() on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging

I recently ran into a problem for which there were no working solutions on Google. I'd like to log an applications's Objective-C messages to the console or to a file. I didn't write the application so I don't have the source code to recompile with logging included. I have a jailbroken iPhone so no restrictions on how to realize this. I even considered doing this through a MobileSubstrate extension (may I hook objc_msgSend for that application to do some logging?), but had not very much ideas. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: When you log you wont get the method names. You'll only get pointers. Method names aren't stored in the final binary. They are stored in a separate file (.dSYM)

Comment: Method selectors are stored in the binary. Objective-c wouldn't work without them. The second argument to objc_msgSend is the selector, which can be changed to a string.

Comment: ughoavgfhw is right (have you ever tried to open a binary generated by ld from Objective-C source?) and it's good to know, but then how to make objc_msgSend to do the log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a logging mechanism for ObjC messages, but I'm not sure whether you'll get method names without symbol files.  Assuming that your jailbroken phone will allow you to run any app under control of the debugger (gdb), you should be able to start the app, set a breakpoint early during the initialization, then do this:

```
(gdb) call (void)instrumentObjcMessageSends(YES)
```

The log file will be written to a text file in the tmp folder.  More details here:

http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/04/22/tracing_objc/

Comment: Thanks Cbranch, you really helped me. I'll try this. (oops, one more question: how do I set a breakpoint?)