# How can I monitor an application's API calls on a jailbroken iOS device?

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, jailbreak, cydia

I am performing a review on an iOS application for which I do not have the source code. In order to gain more control over the environment, I am running the application on a jailbroken iPad.

I'd like to be able to monitor the API calls that the application is making...ideally I'd like to find something like Rohitab's MS Windows based [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), but instead for iOS.

I have done some research and found a project by KennyTM called "[Subjective-C](http://networkpx.blogspot.com/2009/09/introducing-subjective-c.html)" that seems that it may do what I need. I actually have been using a cycript script, along with the [libsubjc.dylib available on the Google code site](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/detail?name=libsubjc.dylib).

However, I have been unable to figure out how to correctly get it to start logging calls for an app. Here's the [link to the cycript script, written by the author](http://networkpx.googlecode.com/svn/etc/libsubjc.cy) of Subjective-C (libsubjc). I pasted the script below as well.

```
/*

libsubjc.cy ... Use libsubjc in cycript.
Copyright (C) 2009  KennyTM~ <kennytm@gmail.com>

[...GPL3...]
*/

dlopen("libsubjc.dylib", 10);
if (!dlfun) {
    function dlfun(fn, encoding, altname) { var f = new Functor(dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, fn), encoding); if (f) this[altname || fn] = f; return f; }
}

dlfun("SubjC_start", "v");
dlfun("SubjC_end", "v");

dlfun("SubjC_set_file", "v^{sFILE=}");
dlfun("SubjC_set_maximum_depth", "vI");
dlfun("SubjC_set_print_arguments", "vB");
dlfun("SubjC_set_print_return_value", "vB");
dlfun("SubjC_set_print_timestamp", "vB");

SubjC_Deny = 0, SubjC_Allow = 1;

dlfun("SubjC_clear_filters", "v");
dlfun("SubjC_filter_method", "vi#:");
dlfun("SubjC_filter_class", "vi#");
dlfun("SubjC_filter_selector", "vi:");
dlfun("SubjC_default_filter_type", "vi");
dlfun("SubjC_filter_class_prefixes", "viI^*");
dlfun("SubjC_filter_class_prefix", "vi*");

dlfun("fopen", "^{sFILE=}**");
dlfun("fclose", "i^{sFILE=}");
```

I have been able to load the libsubjc cycript script, and call the SubjC_start function. However, how do I specify an input filehandle for the line starting with **dlfun("SubjC_set_file", "v^{sFILE=}");**

Has anyone successfully used the "libsubjc.cy" cycript script with the Subjective-C library (libsubjc.dylib) to monitor an app's API calls?

### UPDATE

This is at least generating the output file, but I don't see any information populated within the output file (/tmp/test.txt).

```
cycript -p SpringBoard libsubjc.cy; cycript -p SpringBoard
f = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "w");

SubjC_set_file(f);
SubjC_set_maximum_depth(15);
SubjC_set_print_arguments(YES);
SubjC_set_print_return_value(YES);
SubjC_set_print_timestamp(YES);
SubjC_default_filter_type(SubjC_Deny);
SubjC_start();
//do stuff
SubjC_end();
```

Or, if anyone knows of another way to monitor API calls (w/o source code) on a jailbroken device, please let me know!

Comment: related: [logging objc_msgSend on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640036/logging-objc-msgsend-on-iphone)

Comment: The author of the tool, @KennyTM, is on stack overflow.  Maybe he'll wander by this post and have some ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108920/iphone-strace-dtruss-dtrace-or-equivalent

Comment: A simulator might be a better suit than a jailbroken device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a direct equivalent to API Monitor. However, [Frida](https://frida.re) is a popular tool for mobile app instrumentation, with a [tutorial on iOS usage](https://frida.re/docs/ios/). Once installed, you can trace API calls with a command like `frida-trace -U -i "CCCryptorCreate*" Twitter` to trace calls from the Twitter app to functions starting with `CCCryptorCreate`.

Comment: I asked this question 10 years ago :-) But I think that Frida is the right answer today.

Comment: @Mick Hey, it was only 9 years and 10 months ago.

Answer (score -2):

Set up a proxy server on your computer to redirect and track all the API calls. This is a common way to peak into iOS web traffic and you don't need a jailbroken device.

Comment: Please avoid asking questions (clarification or rhetorical) in answers. Conisder phrasing a conditional answer like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to ...".

Comment: This is not a web api. I'm referring to native syscalls.